# Advanced List sorting Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I am trying to sort a dictionary which is in the form:

```
d = {'+A':234, '-B':212, 'A':454, '-C':991, '-A':124}
```

I want to sort it by key so that it is in the form:

```
+A, A, -A, +B, B, -B, etc
```

I have been trying to use `sorted(d, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]) if len(x) == 2 else x[0])`
but I cannot seem to find any way to sort the symbols correctly since they are not in the correct order on the ascii chart. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sorted(d,...)` is only passing the _keys_ to the lambda function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]) if len(x) == 2 else (x[0], ','))
```

The [ascii value](http://www.asciitable.com/) for `,` lies between `+` and `-`, so you can put a dummy `,` at the end for comparison.

```
>>> d = {'+A':234, '-B':212, 'A':454, '-C':991, '-A':124, '+B':1, 'B':98, '+C':232, 'C':23}
>>> sorted(d, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]) if len(x) == 2 else (x[0], ','))
['+A', 'A', '-A', '+B', 'B', '-B', '+C', 'C', '-C']
```

You can also simply reverse the key and append a `,` for the comparator:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda x: x[::-1] + ',')
```

So +A, A, -A are compared as `A+,`, `A` and `A-,`.

Comment: This only appears to work because there's no `'+B' 'B' '+C' 'C'` in your sample!

Comment: @gnibbler Good catch, I should put the alphabet first in the order. Fixed!

Answer (score 8):

One simple way to do it

```
rank = ['+A', 'A', '-A', '+B', 'B', '-B', ...]
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: rank.index(i[0]))
```

If there are a lot of ranks, it'll be better to use a `dict`

```
rank = {'+A': 0, 'A': 1, '-A': 2, '+B': 3, 'B': 4, '-B': 5, ...}
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: rank[i[0]])
```

You can use a lambda function like this. Note that it's important to use the backward slice to make sure the letters are sorted before their modifiers.

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i:(','+i[0])[::-1])
```

But I think the explicit `rank` is clearer and not prone to bugs like the one in @Hari's answer. (5 people voted for it without noticing the bug so far)

**If you really do just need the keys sorted** (why?), you can simply use `rank.get` instead of a lambda function:

```
>>> rank = {'+A': 0, 'A': 1, '-A': 2, '+B': 3, 'B': 4, '-B': 5, '+C': 6, 'C': 7, '-C': 8}
>>> d = {'+A':234, '-B':212, 'A':454, '-C':991, '-A':124}
>>> sorted(d, key=rank.get)
['+A', 'A', '-A', '-B', '-C']
```

but it's probably better to skip `sorted` altogether

```
>>> rank = ['+A', 'A', '-A', '+B', 'B', '-B', '+C', 'C', '-C']
>>> d = {'+A':234, '-B':212, 'A':454, '-C':991, '-A':124}
>>> [k for k in rank if k in d]
['+A', 'A', '-A', '-B', '-C']
```

If you hate typing all those `'`

```
>>> rank = '+A A -A +B B -B +C C -C'.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd sort by:

- Just the letter - strip off leading `-+`
- Put another weight on the `+` (-1) so it comes first, `-` so it's last (1) otherwise 0

eg:

```
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda L: (L[0].lstrip('-+'), {'-': 1, '+': -1}.get(L[0][0], 0)))
# [('+A', 234), ('A', 454), ('-A', 124), ('-B', 212), ('-C', 991)]
```

Comment: You can also use `L[0][-1]` instead of `lstrip`